# Value of optional type PFQuery? not unwrappped

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I updated to the latest version of Swift/XCode and a PFQuery in my app is generating an error: `Value of optional type 'PFQuery?' not unwrapped`. I know I could add a bang (!) but this only makes the error goes away. It doesn't actually fix the problem. The query used to return results before I upgraded. Here's the code in question:

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint, error) -> Void in

            println(error)

            if error == nil {

                println(geopoint)

                if var user = PFUser.currentUser(){

                    user["location"] = geopoint

                    var query = PFUser.query()
                    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint) //error on this line

                    query.limit = 10
                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) -> Void in
```

Instead of simply making it `query!.whereKey(etc)` what's the best way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for asking, as it is all too tempting just to force-unwrap. Do it like this:

```
if var query = PFUser.query() {
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)
    // ... and so on
}
```

(It is odd that you do not know this, since you are doing it correctly just two lines before with `PFUser.currentUser()`. A case of the left brain not knowing what the right brain is doing?)

Comment: Thanks for that! Someone helped me with that line a few days ago. I wondered if I needed to do the same thing with other similar issues but you answered my question :)

Comment: I actually noticed that it's still bugging me about `query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)`. Says value of optional type PFGeoPoint not unwrapped. I'm pretty sure I need to edit the `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` but not I'm not sure how.

Comment: Same trick. Instead of `if error == nil`, say `if var geopoint = geopoint`.

Comment: Interesting. So saying `if var geopoint = geopoint` is like saying if geopoint isn't nil? It checks to see if the variable exists?

Comment: Yes, what did you think we were doing all this time? :) You might want to read my book, where I discuss this construct: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_binding